# Popup not displaying well

Tags: 7, users

I am using the popup module (http://drupal.org/project/popup) to pop blocks. It works fine with the default core themes in Drupal 7, but when I use my own custom theme, the popup windows break up. I have tried adding CSS styles, but this doesn't seem to work. If any one have an idea on how to solve this, please help me out.

Comment: Could you provide link to website?

Comment: I am developing the site on my local machine.